# Display Facebook image source by id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, photos

I am developing a Facebook application that stores into MySQL the photo[id]. 
I am using Facebook's Graph API to retrieve all of the user's photos and by a radio button the selected photo[id] is stored into mysql.

*The problem is, how should I display the image's source by the id stored?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inspect the Graph Object for that id,

```
graph.facebook.com/photoID
```

For example a photo from facebook.com/facebook

```
http://graph.facebook.com/427100966728
```

This will return a JSON response for which you can choose the size you desire for the source.

For more information see, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

For example in the PHP SDK

```
$a_photo = $facebook->api('/427100966728');

<img src=<?php echo $a_photo['picture'] ?> />
```

Comment: When I try to add the photoid at the end of graph.facebook.com/here it returns false. Any suggestions?

Comment: @cchacholiades if it's false you don't have access to it. You need a valid access token with the proper permissions.

Comment: The permissions I am asking for are those $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => "user_photos, friends_photos, publish_stream", 'fbconnect' =>  0, 'canvas'=>1));

Comment: @cchacholiades what happens when you call $facebook->api('/thephotoid')

Comment: I have done this 
$new = $facebook->api('/thephotoid');
and echo $new 
And it just prints the word array

Comment: @cchacholiades It's a JSON response. So echoing the response will give you an array. You need to parse the response.